# Random text from string array list for button

Tags: android

Example I have 3 buttons:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/q1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/q2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/q3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and and I have text to random from arraylist as bellow code:

```
final String[] answers = private static final String[] answers = {"a", "b", "c", "Vowel", "d", "e", "f", "Vowel"};
```

Bellow is the code get "Vowel" text from arrayList:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (numbers.size()<=4)
    {
      int randomInteger = rnd.nextInt(answers.length);
      if (!numbers.contains(randomInteger))
      {
        numbers.add(randomInteger);
      }
    }
    if (!numbers.contains(3))
    {// here 3 is index of vowel
        int index = rnd.nextInt(numbers.size());//this random to set the index of vowel at random position
        numbers.set(index,3);
    }

    final Button q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    q1.setText(answers[numbers.get(0)]);

    final Button q2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    q2.setText(answers[numbers.get(0)]);

    final Button q3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3);
    q3.setText(answers[numbers.get(0)]);
```

Code above is showing Vowel all the times when activity start... but sometimes Vowel show double because in ArrayList has 2 "Vowel":

```
(Not correct)Example 5 times to start acivity:

1st activity start random look like: a, c, Vowel
2st activity start random look like: b, Vowel, Vowel
3st activity start random look like: Vowel, e, b
4st activity start random look like: Vowel, e, Vowel
5st activity start random look like: Vowel, b, f
```

So, how to show only 1 "Vowel" event in array list has 2 "Vowel":

```
(Correct) Example 5 times to start acivity:

1st activity start random look like: a, c, Vowel
2st activity start random look like: b, Vowel, a
3st activity start random look like: Vowel, e, b
4st activity start random look like: a, e, Vowel
5st activity start random look like: Vowel, b, f
```

The code above no error at all...just sometimes it show 2 "Vowel"..but I want to show only 1 Vowel.

How to modified it?

Thanks

Comment: before set in two and three check the condition which is get in second and third is already available or not

Comment: If you know beforehand in which indexes are the vowel values, you could for example put a boolean a true (like notMoreVowels) and if the next index meet a vowel and this boolean is true, try again. Or you could use an ArrayList and when you get a Vowel value, remove all vowels from the arrayList

Answer (score 0):

You are checking index 3, because it's index of Vowel but what about index 7? It's Vowel too.

```
if (!numbers.contains(3) && !numbers.contains(7))
    {// here 3 is index of vowel
        int index = rnd.nextInt(numbers.size());//this random to set the index of vowel at random position
        numbers.set(index,3);
    }
```